# java lang error when using toArray()

Tags: java, toarray

Here is my basic setup:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("test");
String[] arr = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
System.out.println(arr);
```

And i get the classic error: [Ljava.lang.String;@1540e19d

Can anyone explain and help me fix it?

Comment: Change `System.out.println(arr);` to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

Comment: That is not an "error"... It's just the `toString()` method of `Object` that is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
for(String s : arr){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Instead of `System.print.out()`;